# Downloading a file returned by JS function in Pug/Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, pug

In the Angular7/Pug application there used to be a file download link. The file was served in the following way (in table.component.pug)

```
div
    p File to download:
    a([href]="downloadLink", download="table.xlsx")
        some-icon
        span some-text
```

Right now I want to change it. I want user to be able to download a file returned from a function. Function is in table.component.ts:

```
getTable(): Observable<any> {
        return this.service.getTable();
    }
```

How should I write the pug div? I've tried something like:

```
div
    p MS Excel table:
    input((click)='getDownload()')
        some-icon
        span some-text
```

But as I am a back-end develper, the code above doesn't work :-) Plese tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parentheses around the element's attribute.  Try this:

```
div
  p MS Excel table:
  input(click= 'getDownload()')
    some-icon
    span some-text
```